# Apache 403 Error - where is the fault?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, alias, forbidden

My environment: Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop Edition

So I am trying to access a file through my localhost and Apache is giving me a 403 error.

On `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, I've added this line :

```
# wan27 hostel
Include "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/apache2.conf"
```

The contents of `/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/apache2.conf`:

```
Alias /hostel "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/"

<Directory "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/">

DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
# allow from all

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
  php_flag track_vars On
  php_value include_path .
</IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Then make sure folder is accessible to www-data, on my terminal:

```
chown -R www-data "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel"
```

Then restart Apache, Apache does not complain about some misconfiguration

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                           ... waiting                                                                                                       [ OK ]
```

Then, on Chrome, entering address http://localhost/hostel/checkin.php, I get:

```
403
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /hostel/checkin.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

The contents of `/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/checkin.php`:

```
hola
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's is apache error log? Also, I don't see virtualhost entry, could you share it? It might be relevant.

Comment: Having a look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I see this line: `[Tue Mar 29 09:34:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /hostel/checkin.php denied`. Now a question about the file: it should be `/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel/checkin.php` and not `/hostel/chekin.php`, but in this case log should show a Not found error instead of Permissions denied ?...

Comment: @rvs are you talking about the virtual host conf file?

Comment: Also, I've tried to move the hostel folder somewhere else and same issue :(

Comment: Now I've moved the hostel folder to the root / and it works ?! Could it be that placing a file in the Ubuntu One folder not the best idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that www-data can read each of the dirs in the path?  start at the top level dir and work your way  down.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing slashes on your Alias and Directory directives:

```
Alias /hostel "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel"
<Directory "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu One/hostel">
```

Answer (score -1):

If it works after moving the hostel folder to another location, the problem may be that you need to escape the space:

```
<Directory "/home/francoisrv/Ubuntu\ One/hostel/">
 ..
</Directory>
```

Comment: This isn't really fit as an answer. Please xplain your entire answer rather than just referring to a comment.